# PyQT5 QWebEngineView Twitch

Tags: python, pyqt5, twitch, qwebengineview

I'm experimenting with QWebEngineView and Twitch streams. Currently it seems that it is unable to play the streams in the web engine. I'm getting the following error while trying to load a stream.

```
js: Player stopping playback - error MasterPlaylist:11 (ErrorNotAvailable code 404 - Failed to load playlist)
js: Player stopping playback - error Player:2 (ErrorNotSupported code 0 - No playable format)
```

I'm wondering if anyone know how this might be fixed. Thanks.
Also if you have a completely different approach to loading twitch streams in python feel free.

Here is some test code.

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings
from qframelesswindow import FramelessWindow, StandardTitleBar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import sys


class CustomTitleBar(StandardTitleBar):
    """ Custom title bar """

    def __init__(me, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)


class Window(FramelessWindow):
    def __init__(me, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        me.setTitleBar(CustomTitleBar(me))
        me.titleBar.raise_()
        screen = me.screen().geometry()
        x = int((screen.width() - 800) / 2)
        y = int((screen.height() - 450) / 2)
        me.setGeometry(x, y, 800, 450)

    def showLive(me, follow):
        # open stream in qwebengineview
        me.stream = QWebEngineView(me)
        settings = me.stream.settings()
        settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        settings.setAttribute(
            QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True)
        me.stream.setGeometry(0, 64, me.width(), me.height() - 64)
        me.stream.load(QUrl(f"https://www.twitch.tv/{follow}"))
        me.stream.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
window.showLive("3v1lxd")
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: First of all, please try to provide a valid [mre]: the basics of debugging demands that you put all your efforts in trying to exclude anything that doesn't seem to affect the issue. And I frankly doubt that using `FramelessWindow` or `StandardTitleBar` may: still, I may be wrong, but this results in two important aspects: 1. if they *do* create the result, you need to provide their code; 2. if they don't, their usage is completely useless for the question. That said, you just said a very vague "the following error while trying to load a stream": can you please clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: sorry about the misunderstanding. I get that you don't want the tiny bit of extra code but it really doesn't effect anything as you say other than aesthetics that i just ripped out of my project to build a quick test. What i mean by loading a stream is just visiting the website using qwebengineview. the errors show in terminal when the engine attempts to play the video after the site is loaded.

Comment: I understand that, but that's exactly the reason for which we ask for a MRE. We cannot know what you did in modules we know nothing about, which means that we cannot exclude that the issue might be in those modules. Providing a *valid* MRE is what help us *help you* (and, coincidentally, it's also what usually helps people to debug the issue on their own).

Comment: No worries I will try to provide better MRE in the future. I was able to find a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution using streamlink and VLC

```
from qframelesswindow import FramelessWindow, StandardTitleBar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame
import streamlink
import sys
import vlc


class CustomTitleBar(StandardTitleBar):
    def __init__(me, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)


class Window(FramelessWindow):
    def __init__(me, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        me.setTitleBar(CustomTitleBar(me))
        me.titleBar.raise_()
        screen = me.screen().geometry()
        x = int((screen.width() - 800) / 2)
        y = int((screen.height() - 450) / 2)
        me.setGeometry(x, y, 800, 450)
        me.stream = QFrame(me)
        me.stream.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 450)
        me.instance = vlc.Instance()

    def showLive(me, follow):
        # open stream in streamlink
        session = streamlink.Streamlink()
        streams = session.streams(f"https://www.twitch.tv/{follow}")
        if streams is not None:
            stream = streams["best"]
            # open stream in vlc player and add to window
            player = vlc.MediaPlayer(stream.url)
            player.set_hwnd(me.stream.winId())
            player.play()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
window.showLive("pokelawls")
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```